# Is there any computation formalism based on general relativity?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

Quantum mechanical principles have already been used to attack computer science problems in the form of quantum computing. In a similar vein, is there any usage of general relativity principles to generate algorithms in favor of computer-scientific problems? One (fairly trivial) example would be solving the shortest path problem, as the solution to the geodesic equation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason quantum computing is useful is not (just) that the problems in QM are applicable to problems that'd we'd like to solve in computing generally, but because we can *physically realize* setups that model these problems in a way such that the (quantum) dynamics of the physical system solves our problem for us. In classical physics, the Difference Engine is useful because it reduces a problem of abstract arithmetic into a physical state in such a way that the physical dynamics of that state (i.e. turning the handle of the Engine) correspond to solving the problem, and the same reduction takes the "end state" of the physical machine back to the correct (abstract) answer. The same fundamentally applies for quantum computers, they just have access to dynamics that can perform certain operations faster than classical machines.

In (practical) relativity, there's not really the same opportunity for exploitation, because the local dynamics are still classical and you don't gain any new "magic powers" like you do in quantum. You can't build physical systems that make nature solve the problems for us. Time dilation in principle would be such a power, but there's no practical benefit in making a device slower. That said, Relativity may be a good inspiration for how to think about distributed systems, down to even multi-threaded programs on the same host, because the former is essentially a set of rules for determing which events within spacetime are ordered with respect to one another, and in a very fundamental sense, the (apparent) order of everything else cannot be relied upon. A similar idea of "locality" shows up in programming notions like the [actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), where it becomes very intuitive that anything "not in the same place" is not syncronised and it is unsafe to rely on the ordering of remote events.

However, on the (massively) *impractical* side, Relativity is also the theory that formalised notions of time travel. If you have a time machine that works in the sense of "you already changed the past", this *is* a magic power, because it allows you to build [time loop logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle#Time-loop_logic) which can solve $\text{PSPACE}$ problems in $\text{P}$ time, by essentially threatening to cause a paradox if you don't get what you want. The scheme goes like this:

1. Receive a candidate answer from the future
2. Check whether the answer is right
3. If it isn't, send back to the past the "next" candidate, however that's defined in the context.
4. If it is, send back the value you got as-is.

The issue being of course, 3 means that the value you sent back is not the one you received, which is paradoxical. The self-consistency principle asserts that a paradox cannot happen, so just like [Raymond Chen's time-travelling undefined behaviour](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/), we conclude that the only possible case is 4, meaning step 2 cannot fail and therefore the answer we got in step 1 *must* have been correct all along, even though nobody originally found it at any point.

(Sadly, nobody knows how to build a time machine, so whether this would actually work is of course up in the air.)

Comment: There exist some papers about computational advantages you could "theoretically" get if you put computers on specially chosen orbits around black holes. For example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379719304036 and https://www.scopus.com/record/display.uri?eid=2-s2.0-0141563264&origin=inward&txGid=e90fcba95daa8fd070ad4ebd3d06ca9f
The basic idea is that you can have an algorithm that takes infinite time searching for something in vain and emits nothing, but the relativistic geometry of spacetime allows you to observe all the algorithm's outputs during a finite time.